How to deploy Django app in docker with UV
I am writing a Dockerfile Configuration for a Django app. I am usin uv to manage my dependencies in a virtualenv. The app runs normally outside the container, but when I try to run it from the container, it can't find the django package:
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

This tells me that the recreation of the virtualenv inside the container is not working as it should. But I cannot find the problem. Here is my Dockerfile:
FROM ghcr.io/astral-sh/uv:python3.12-bookworm-slim

WORKDIR /app

# Enable bytecode compilation
ENV UV_COMPILE_BYTECODE=1

# Copy from the cache instead of linking since it's a mounted volume
ENV UV_LINK_MODE=copy

#ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
#ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends gcc python3-dev libpq-dev gunicorn &&\
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install the project's dependencies using the lockfile and settings
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/uv \
        --mount=type=bind,source=uv.lock,target=uv.lock \
        --mount=type=bind,source=pyproject.toml,target=pyproject.toml \
        uv sync --frozen --no-install-project --no-dev

# Then, add the rest of the project source code and install it
# Installing separately from its dependencies allows optimal layer caching
ADD . /app
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/uv \
        uv sync --frozen --no-dev


#COPY --from=builder /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/

# Place executables in the environment at the front of the path
ENV PATH="/app/.venv/bin:$PATH"
ENTRYPOINT []

RUN useradd -m appuser && chown -R appuser:appuser /app
USER appuser
WORKDIR /app/myproject
EXPOSE 9090
CMD ["gunicorn", "myproject.wsgi:application", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:9090"]

I am also using the following docker-compose file to manage the container
services:
  web:
      # Build the image from the Dockerfile in the current directory
    build: .
    # Host the app on port 8000
    ports:
      - 9090:9090
    networks:
      - app_network
    restart: unless-stopped

networks:
  app_network:
    driver: bridge

I should say that I based this Dockerfile on the example provide by astral-sh.
Why does the installation of the dependencies not work?

Not sure, but installing gunicorn using the Debian package manager might confuse the venv configuration. Have you tried installing it via requirements.txt (or whatever method you are using to install dependencies using uv sync)?

Try replacing the command:
CMD ["gunicorn", "myproject.wsgi:application", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:9090"]
with:
CMD ["uv", "run", "gunicorn", "myproject.wsgi:application", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:9090"] 
and try again
